# Update value from database on button click from Controller Laravel

Tags: laravel

I wanted to do update but do not need to go into edit

so i use this button to do the update

[image: Button for update]

when i click the green button, the value of "new" is going to change

this is my blade:

```
<form class="btn-group" action="{{ route('perjanjians.konfirmasi', ['id' => $item->id]) }}" method="POST">
                                                            @csrf
                                                            @method('PATCH')
                                                            <label class="btn btn-success text-center">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Konfirmasi</button>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </form>
```

This is my Controller for update:

```
public function update_konfirmasi(Request $request, Perjanjian $perjanjian)
    {
        // dd($perjanjian);
        $request->validate([
            'schedule_doctor_id'    => 'nullable',
            'email'    => 'nullable',
            'no_tlp'    => 'nullable',
            'tanggal'    => 'nullable',
        ]);

        $perjanjian->nama_lengkap       = $request->get('nama_lengkap') ;
        $perjanjian->email              = $request->get('email') ;
        $perjanjian->no_tlp             = $request->get('no_tlp') ;
        $perjanjian->tanggal            = $request->get('tanggal') ;
        $perjanjian->is_confirm         = 'confirm';
        dd($perjanjian);
        $perjanjian->save();

        return back();
    }
```

but when i click, the data from $perjanjian variables its gone, but the is_confirm is changed

[image: Like this]

where i do something wrong when updating?

Comment: if values can be nullable why to waste time on validating it, in your form you are just submitting your form, where are the values

Comment: the values is exists, i use nullable to test it if it was on validation issues. sorry i forgot to change it @bhucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're expliciting say they are `null` by doing

```php
$perjanjian->nama_lengkap = $request->get('nama_lengkap')
```

Since you're not sending any value named `nama_lengkap` in your form request, it's equivalent to

```php
$perjanjian->nama_lengkap = null
```

If you need to fill theses fields from an another form, I would suggest you to add a new and dedicated method for this one

```php
public function confirm(Request $request, Perjanjian $perjanjian) {

        $perjanjian->is_confirm = 'confirm';
        dd($perjanjian);
        $perjanjian->save();

        return back();
}
```

---

Edit
Also I noticed you're using `['id' => $item->id]` I'm assuming your route is something like `Route::patch('/confirm/{id}', ...)`

Your method expect the parameter `perjanjian`.
Consequently it will be `null` since it receive `id` which will make a an empty model of `Perjanjian`.

You should change to  `['perjanjian' => $item->id]` and `Route::patch('/confirm/{perjanjian}', ...)` in order to make your Model Binding working as expected

Comment: okay so the reason i use get is i try to get the old values of the fields. the values is exist, but when i try to update only 1 column, it turns other field to null

Comment: Can you add the full form ? It seems they are not sent then.

Comment: In case you didn't know `$request->get('nama_lengkap')` will get the value of `<input name="nama_lengkap">`. You don't need to re-assign `$perjanjian->nama_lengkap = $previousValue`. It won't be gone unless you say so.

Comment: @ErandaDava I have uptaded my answer

Comment: okay, i'll try to edit with your answer and come back here later, thankyou in advance

Comment: Nice!, its working. so the problem is the parameters i changed id to perjanjian as you said, now it works. thank you!